# LSTM input vector

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm

Trying to understand how LSTM works, i have found this article:

https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

Consider we have a matrix with $N$ rows that contains time series (input vector) with $k$ values/measurements per series $x = [x(1), x(2), ..., x(k)]$. So, the matrix has shape $N.k$.

In this figure:

[image]

What does $X_{t-1}$, $X_t$, $X_{t+1}$, ..., means? They are each a whole timeseries with $k$ values (for example, $X_{t-1}$ would be my first time series, $X_{t}$ would be my second, and so on)? Or $X_{t-1}$ always represent the first measurement of a timeseries, $x(1)$, $X_{t}$ is the second measurement $x(2)$, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $X_t$ are the measurements at time $t$. If you have multiple measurements at each $t$ (for instance, temperature at time $t$ and humidity at time $t$), then $X_t$ is the vector holding all of the measurements at $t$.